# Python nested loop working with data file

Tags: python

I've got a file with data and I want to search for the maximum reading per each hour.

```
def maximum():
source = open ( 'dataV.csv', 'r' )
result = open ( 'dataV-max.csv', 'w' )
line = source.readline()

max_num = '0'

while line != '' :
    for time in range(0, 24):
        line = source.readline()
        if time == line [ 12:14 ] and line [22:len(line)] <= max_num :
            max_num = line [ 22:len(line) ]
            print ( max_num )
            result.write ( str(max_num) )

source.close()
result.close()
```

Okay so I updated my code, but it stays only in one hour.

```
def maximum():
source = open ( 'dataV.csv', 'r' )
result = open ( 'dataV-max.csv', 'w' )
line = source.readline()

line = source.readline()

max_hour = line[23:]
hour = line[12:14]

while line != '':
    hour = line[12:14]
    line = source.readline()
    if hour == line[12:14]:
        if line[23:] > max_hour:
            max_hour = line[23:]
        result.write(line)

source.close()
result.close()
```

I've got a problem with the nested loop I think. I don't understand how to make it go through the whole file.

Here is some part of the file:

```
'time PST', saturn03.820.A.AlgaeWatch [microg/l]
'2014-04-25 00:04:48',3.35
'2014-04-25 00:04:54',3.225
'2014-04-25 00:05:00',3.15
'2014-04-25 00:07:48',3.4
'2014-04-25 00:07:54',3.4
'2014-04-25 00:08:00',3.375
'2014-04-25 00:10:48',3.45
'2014-04-25 00:10:54',3.325
'2014-04-25 00:11:00',3.425
'2014-04-25 00:13:49',3.45
'2014-04-25 00:13:54',3.5
'2014-04-25 00:14:00',3.525
'2014-04-25 00:16:48',3.725
```

Comment: Will you please clear the question a bit. What will be the content of the file ? Sample file content will be fine if you give. Please give a sample content and what you are expecting from that sample content.

Comment: @sagar ok I did it

Comment: Thank you for the input content. Will you please let me know what is the output you expect.

Comment: Thanks for providing the input sample, but will the 2nd line really miss the leading single quote? Then you will need complex logic in your script to account for errors like these ... please correct or explicitly state which errors in data should be accepted/ignored or corrected.

Comment: okay, thank you for help. I want to have the maximum number in each hour that goes after comma in each line.

Comment: So, you want to know the highest value recorded in the interval of one hour? For examples - between `2014-04-25 00:04:00` and  `2014-04-25 00:05:00`, `3.35` is the max value recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input:

```
'time PST', saturn03.820.A.AlgaeWatch [microg/l]
'2014-04-25 00:04:48',3.35
'2014-04-25 00:04:54',3.225
'2014-04-25 00:05:00',3.15
'2014-04-25 00:07:48',3.4
'2014-04-25 00:07:54',3.4
'2014-04-25 00:08:00',3.375
'2014-04-25 00:10:48',3.45
'2014-04-25 00:10:54',3.325
'2014-04-25 00:11:00',3.425
'2014-04-25 00:13:49',3.45
'2014-04-25 00:13:54',3.5
'2014-04-25 01:14:00',3.525
'2014-04-25 02:16:48',3.725
```

The program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
"""Usually a ready made file parser like csv module or even panda
et al. for more complete service is the way to go here but one may
want to know how to basically iterate and parse a little one self.
This is also for the date time parsing which one typically also
delegates to datetime module or the like."""
from __future__ import print_function
import sys


def hourly_maxima(in_file, out_file):
    """Extract calendar hourly maximum readings from in_file,
    write to out_file. If files do not exist or are
    not accessible exceptions will happily raise ;-).
    Input is expected to be ordered ascending by time
    stamp."""

    field_sep = ','
    with open(in_file, 'rt') as f_i, open(
            out_file, 'wt') as f_o:  # May raise here
        f_i.readline()  # Ignore header, be optimistic

        ts_raw = None
        hourly_maximum = None
        current_hour = None  # Group by calendar hour stored in tuples
        date_sep = '-'
        # Expect sample data line to document flow:
        # '2014-04-25 00:04:48',3.35
        for line in f_i.readlines():  # Digest rest of lines
            if not line:
                break  # stop on first empty line
            ts, reading = line.strip().split(field_sep)  # May raise ...
            r_float = float(reading)  # May raise ...

            # Map timestamp ts to calendar hour
            ts_raw = ts.strip("'")
            year, month, day = ts_raw[:10].split(date_sep)
            hour = ts_raw[11:13]
            cand_hour = (year, month, day, hour)
            if current_hour is None:
                current_hour = cand_hour

            if cand_hour == current_hour:  # We seek the maximum
                if hourly_maximum is None or r_float > hourly_maximum:
                    hourly_maximum = r_float
            else:  # report hourly maximum of previous hour and reset
                print(ts_raw, hourly_maximum)  # Also report matching hour?
                f_o.write('%s\n' % (str(hourly_maximum)))
                current_hour = cand_hour
                hourly_maximum = r_float

        # Flush the last result kept in hourly_maximum:
        print(ts_raw, hourly_maximum)  # Also report matching hour?
        f_o.write('%s\n' % (str(hourly_maximum)))


def main():
    """Drive the extraction."""
    in_file = 'dataV.csv' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1]
    out_file = 'dataV-max.csv' if len(sys.argv) < 3 else sys.argv[2]

    hourly_maxima(in_file, out_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Yields:

```
2014-04-25 01:14:00 3.5
2014-04-25 02:16:48 3.525
2014-04-25 02:16:48 3.725
```

on std output and in the file:

```
3.5
3.525
3.725
```

Now is this what you wanted? I guess so. Lots of room for improvement, hardening and additional elegance though.

Keep up with learning python.

PS: Sorry was offline for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Hero you go:

```
import sys
def fileParser(sourcefileName, destinationfileName):
    fd = open(sourcefileName)
    lines = fd.readlines()
    hourMaxDict = dict()
    for line in lines[1:]:
            hour = line.split(" ")[1].split(":")[0]
            maxRead = float(line.split(",")[-1].rstrip())
            if hour in hourMaxDict.keys() and hourMaxDict[hour] > maxRead:
                    continue
            else:
                    hourMaxDict[hour] = maxRead
    destFd = open(destinationfileName, "a")
    for key, val in hourMaxDict.iteritems():
            val = str(val) + "\n"
            destFd.write(str(val))
    fd.close()
    destFd.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileParser(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Execution:

```
techie@gateway2:~$ python fileReader.py sourceFile.txt destinationFile.txt
```

Input File Content:

```
'time PST', saturn03.820.A.AlgaeWatch [microg/l]
'2014-04-25 00:04:48',3.35
'2014-04-25 00:04:54',3.225
'2014-04-25 00:04:48',3.35
'2014-04-25 00:04:54',3.225
'2014-04-25 00:05:00',3.15
'2014-04-25 00:07:48',3.4
'2014-04-25 00:07:54',3.4
'2014-04-25 00:08:00',3.375
'2014-04-25 00:10:48',3.45
'2014-04-25 00:10:54',3.325
'2014-04-25 00:11:00',3.425
'2014-04-25 00:13:49',3.45
'2014-04-25 00:13:54',3.5
'2014-04-25 01:14:00',3.525
'2014-04-25 01:16:48',3.725
```

Output File content:

```
3.5
3.725
```

You can use split extensively to achieve the same thing.
Hope this will help. :-)